# "to"infinitive to mean "if "

Tags: sentence-structure

my grammar book has the following explanation on the usage of "to infinitive"

> You will take him for an American **to hear** him speak English.
> = You will take him for an American **if you hear** him speak English.

Never have I come across with such usage during my 8-year stay in nz,
is it a common usage?
isn't the meaning of "to hear" a little bit ambiguous even to the natives?
or do you guys understand the first sentence as clearly as the second one?

Comment: The adverbial highlighted element in ***To hear him speak**, you'd think he was American* can also be expressed using progressive participles: ***Hearing him speak*** and ***Having heard him speak**, I'm inclined to agree*.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of an [infinitive adverbial phrase](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/whats-an-infinitive-or-infinitive-phrase/#:%7E:text=Adverbial%20Infinitives,verbs%2C%20adjectives%2C%20or%20adverbs.&text=It%20modifies%20the%20main%20adjective,to%20go%20to%20the%20party.%E2%80%9D). They are relatively common in everyday English, but most are a lot easier to understand than your particular sentence. Other examples are:

> Practice doing something kind **to help ease the suffering of others** - *Zen habits, Leo Babauta 2011*
> Did it make you feel good **to see him**? - *Best American Short Stories, Stephen King, 2007*

Replacing **to** with **if you** makes a conjunction clause, which is also an adverbial.

Adverbials can be used at the end of the sentence as in your example, or as an adverbial prefix. As with all adverbial prefixes, a comma is recommended if it's more than three or four words long:

> To hear him speak English, you will take him for an American.

Comment: "**To hear him speak**, you **would** take him ..." / "if you **hear** him speak, you **will** take him ..." / "If you **heard** him speak, you **would** take him ..."